# How to specify target in the TakesScreenshot interface's getScreenshotAs method

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, documentation, screenshot

On reading the [Java documentation of `TakesScreenshot` interface](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TakesScreenshot.html#getScreenshotAs-org.openqa.selenium.OutputType-), it was observed that the method syntax and description for `getScreenshotAs` are:

> ```
> getScreenshotAs(OutputType<X> target)
> ```
>
> Capture the screenshot and store it in the specified location.

But the example usage shown is:

```
File screenshotFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

How can I specify the target for `getScreenshotAs` and why do we use `OutputType.File` and not `OutputType< File>`?

How to interpret this Java documentation? I understood the syntax as:

```
getScreenshotAs(OutputType<File> Destination)
```

where Destination is:

```
File Destination = new File("D:/new.png");
```

Comment: *"How can I specify the target for getScreenshotAs method"* - the example shows you that, you pass one of the `OutputType` values. *"why we use OutputType.File and not OutputFile?"* - well, what *is* `OutputFile`? If you're trying to ask how to get that screenshot file to somewhere specific, per the docs, *"It is up to users to make a copy of this file."* None of this seems specific to testing or QA.

Comment: The example shows how to get a specific type, not the target

Comment: What do you mean by *"the target"*, though?

Comment: The syntax shows shows getscreenshotas(outputtype<x> target) ; i was understanding it as getscreenshotas(outputtype<File> Destination) , were destination is a target location; File destination = new File("D:/test.png").

Comment: About outputFIle , i meant outputtype<File> , it was an human error. Sorry for that, i have updated it

Comment: I know how to get and store screenshots. I was just concerned on how to infer the Java documentation. If my understanding is wrong please correct me so that i can use it while going through other java documentations.

Comment: You can't use `OutputType<File>` because that's a *type*; `OutputType.FILE` is a *value*, which implements the `OutputType` interface to return a `File`. `target` can't just be a `File`, it needs to be something that implements the required interface. Again, though, none of this is specific to testing or QA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Documentation wording**:

> Capture the screenshot and store it in the specified **location**.
>
> https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TakesScreenshot.html

An object in memory is also a valid location. The word location does not only mean a file location on disk. Thus one could argue that the word "location" could reference a object that is returned by the method.

I do think the documentation is confusing. It could read something like: "Returns a screenshot object of the chosen output type."

If you want to challenge the documentation [create an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues).

**Syntax**:

The target has to be one of the three OutputTypes.

The [OutputType documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/OutputType.html) shows there are three default types for X:

```
static OutputType<java.lang.String> BASE64 
static OutputType<byte[]>   BYTES
static OutputType<java.io.File> FILE
```

You could also create your own implementation of an OutputType, as Jonrsharpe suggests.

The syntax is:

```
getScreenshotAs(OutputType.ONEOFTHETHREETYPES)
```

The target is an output-type target, not a target destination. You could argue target might be a confusing name. The method returns either a String, Bytes or a File object containing the screenshot. Afterwards you decide how to store it in a destination.

Comment: Ok so,  as String(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length) ,means String method takes a byte array, a int offset and int length. getScreenshotAs(OutputType<File> Destination) means that getScreenshotas takes an argument 'target' which can be of any of the three outputtype. Thank you so much.

Comment: @PDHide actually not just those three - those are the only ones with precanned implementations, but you could write another implementation for a different `T` (or, for that matter, another implementation for one of those three, e.g. an `OutputType<File>` that directly used a real file `getScreenshotAs(new MyFileOutputType("path/to/something.ext"))`).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Nice addition, added to the answers you can also implement your own OutputType :)